# Jenkins last Organization Scan details

Tags: jenkins

For organisation type job, is there a way to fetch details of last run of `OrganizationScan`? I'm mostly interested in whether the last `OrganizationScan` is still running or completed. For multibranch Jenkins job, I see `/build/api/json` can be used, but this doesn't seem to work with organisation scan job. I checked `/api/xml/` of organisation scan but it doesn't talk about the state of last scan.